# creat new options to joomla component when creating new menu item

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I searched internet for good explanation how to create additional options when creating new menu item.

For example: i created component to sell chips of different companiens when creating menu option it to show only chips of company xyz and not from all companies.

Similar work-flow is when we want to add article as new menu item.
Field where 'Required Settings' is.

Please show me code responsible for it or good tutorial .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for menu options for your custom component, you can add menu parameters in the below file-

```
site/components/com_component/views/viewname/tmpl/default.xml
```

Here is the explanation how to create menu params-

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_06#site.2Fviews.2Fhelloworld.2Ftmpl.2Fdefault.xml

For the complete list of params you can check here-
http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types