# how can I add menu item specific parameters and read them on joomla 2.5 menu?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-component

I am programming a little on joomla(2.5) and I created a component, which works great, now I found a problem... I need that component to receive a paramenter (from a joomla's menu) and indicate a value, then with that value I will calculate some stuffs (like a module's parameter).

So, after searching I found this doc

http://docs.joomla.org/Component_parameters

Which is great (if would work at all), but I have a problem.. I can not add any parameter, I copied and pasted the code for the XML where I should set my parameter field ... and doesnt work, I tried with the fields Ive used for modules, and it does appear, but I cant read them...

Any idea how to do it?

Here is my xml.

```
<metadata>
  <state>
    <params>
    <param name="mytextvalue" type="text" default="Some text" label="Enter some text" description="" size="10" />
    </params>
  </state>
</metadata>
```

please help

Answer (score 2):

Params are removed from 1.6 and above joomla versions.So you'll have to use fieldset and field instead.
[About Different Fields](http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types)

May this will be helpful to you-
[How to creat new options to joomla component when creating new menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416547/creat-new-options-to-joomla-component-when-creating-new-menu-item/13416802#13416802)

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called `config.xml` and add this in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <fieldset name="settings" label="Configuration Settings" description="Description Goes Here">
        <field name="mytextvalue" type="text" default="Some text" label="Enter some text" description="" size="10" />       
    </fieldset>
</config>
```

To view the parameters, add `JToolBarHelper::preferences('com_yourcomponentname');` to the display function in the **view.html.php** file. This will add a buttons called "Options" on the Toolbar of your component in the backend. Click it to view the parameters.